# DelayedJob fails silently when couldn't connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-2

So, i have a big rails application that is using delayed_job to send emails and SMS to the users.

Once in a while, the delayed_job process will simply stop working without any message on the logs. I have finally pinpointed the problem as the delayed_job process crashs when it coulnd't  connect to the database.

Is there any configuration i can make so it will retry the connection instead of just crashing? I've tried setting the `reconnect: true` on the `database.yml` file with no success.

Another option that i'm looking for is maybe using a monitoring tool like god or bluepill.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -m flag when you start delayed job - that should start a separate monitor process that in my experience has been very good about restarting the process.

Comment: Still need more time to test it, but it doesn't seems to be working, but thanks for the suggestion.